# How to change the UIWebView height Programatically in Swift iOS (Xcode 6.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, autolayout

i'm in trouble. i'm currently using a uiwebview to display content. but i want to show content without scrolling in uiwebview.

Below the code. look it

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {

    var newBounds: CGRect = webView.bounds
    newBounds.size.height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    webView.bounds = newBounds

}
```

but it won't be change its size. Anyone know what should i do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `webView.frame.size = webView.scrollView.contentSize`

Comment: but my webview inside a scrollview.

Comment: I have answered for your "show content fit without scrolling in uiwebview"

Comment: sorry for that. i want to show content without scrolling. means webview height change acc to content.

Comment: Try this answer:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666484/html-content-fit-in-uiwebview-without-zooming-out)!

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to automatically scale your content. Try this:

```
// Assumes 'webView' is a property
overload func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
}
```

You can also set this property in the storyboard/xib. Note that this enables zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 let webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
 webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.jogendra.com")))
 webV.delegate = self;
 self.view.addSubview(webV)
```

Thanks